# Statistical thought experiment (possibly Bayesian) about survey sampling and propensity scores

Tags: bayesian, sampling, resampling, propensity-scores

For some practical application I recently came about the following thought experiment. Can anybody help?

Suppose we administer a survey A to measure a variable $Y$. The response probabilities may depend on $Y$, as in $$P(R_a=1|Y)$$ where $R_a$ is the response indicator, 0 for nonresponse, 1 for response. We also administer a second survey B, for example using some other fieldwork protocol, which leads to $$P(R_b=1|Y).$$ Now assume we can estimate both response propensities, because we have $Y$ from some external source. The goal is now to find a sample which in expectation has response probability $$P(R_a=0,R_b=1|Y).$$ My idea is to sample from sample B with estimated selection probabilities $1-\hat{P}(R_a=1|Y)$. If I do this a large number of times, does the resulting sample have 'on average' the required selection probability?

**Edit**: This feels very Bayesian. The question could maybe be put differently as: is it possible to simulate the bivariate distribution of two discrete variables from their marginal distributions?

Comment: My intuition is it's not possible because the covariance of the response indicators is not observed. But I might be wrong.